# Radio Group and Table Layout Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create a horizontal layout using table row and radio group but it always ended us being vertical.This is only the half xml

```
       <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <RadioGroup
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="false">
                <RadioButton
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:id="@+id/food_best"
                        android:layout_gravity="center|left"
                        />
                <RadioButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        />
                <RadioButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        />
            </RadioGroup>

    </TableRow>
```

[image]

I am sure you might have got the idea of what i want. If i change the orientation to vertical it will still be the same.

Thanks for your help guys.

Update as suggested by **shaikhmanzoor**
This is what it looks like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

set orientation of radiogroup like

```
<RadioGroup
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation='horizontal'>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set the orientation to horizontal and it should work.
`android:orientation="horizontal"`

Comment: Dude, thanks for the response but I have updated my post please have a look. cheers